# openapi code generator - use @Digits instead of @DecimalMax / @DecimalMin

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation, bigdecimal, openapi-generator

Below is my field `num1` where I always need only 2 digits after precision point, so I used `minimum` and `maximum` constraints in the contract.

```
properties:
  num1:
    type: number
    minimum: 10.01
    maximum: 50.99
```

I have enabled `useBeanValidation` option  while generating code. So, the above openapi field `num1` generates `BigDecimal` `java` mapping as shown below:

```
@Valid
@DecimalMin("10.01") @DecimalMax("50.99") 
  public BigDecimal getNum1() {
    return num1;
  }
```

With this, I expected `10.45` is valid and `10.451` is invalid. But, `10.451` is treated as valid. I understand, logically `10.451` is valid because it is greater than the `minimum` value.

I found `@Digits` provides the expected behavior, but I need some help to configure `openapi-generator-maven-plugin (v 3.3.1)` to use `@Digits` annotation instead of `@DecimalMin / @DecimalMax` annotations. Anyone come across this kind of issue?

Below are my `config options` for `openapi-generator-maven-plugin`:

```
<configOptions>
  <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
  <dateLibrary>java8-localdatetime</dateLibrary>
  <sourceFolder>openapi</sourceFolder>
  <useBeanValidation>true</useBeanValidation>
  <performBeanValidation>true</performBeanValidation>
  <bigDecimalAsString>true</bigDecimalAsString>
</configOptions>
```